# IBM MobileFirst HTTPS issue

Tags: ios, https, ibm-mobilefirst

Currently our backend server (7.1) has been setup using SSL and we had manage to access the operation console and app center console via HTTPS without any problem.

However from the app, whenever the app launch it will throw a connection failed error. The app has been rebuilt using the HTTPS protocol to connect to the backend. Previous version that uses HTTP works well.

From the log we found this line:

```
Response Error : An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
```

After some search, I found this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451322/mobilelfirst-7-1-ios9-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the) which states that the issue is caused by the iOS ATS policy, and i would need to setup the SSL according to Apple's criteria.

After setting up the server as per instructed, i restarted the server and retry. Getting the below issue instead:

```
CWWKO0801E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

My concern is, since on the App, we have turn on the Arbitrary load for ATS, and as such it should not be checking the ATS setting. Why is the app still throwing the SSL error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your info.plist file replace the existing NSAppTransportSecurity key with:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

the issue will be resolved.

**Edit:**

In case you were able to enable SSL on the server, then following this doc:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_enforce_TLS.html

you need to add the following config to your info.plist:

```
<key>protocol</key>
<string>https</string>

<key>port</key>
<string>10443</string>
```

The Port will be your firewall port

Comment: Yes i did just that, but still the same error persists....I'll try again in a while just in case i put the wrong stuff..

Comment: If you were able to resolve the SSL issue on your server by modifying the Firewall, then you need to enable it on the device too. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, will try it when have the chance. Meanwhile we were able to bypass the ATS by setting the arbitrary load setting AND clear of the exception domains list, and rebuild the whole apps again. Will keep this in mind.